# Can you connect 2 Facebook apps to one iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

We are currently using a few different apps on Facebook for different platforms for marketing purposes - one for our production site, one for our iPhone app and one for our iPad app.

Would it be possible / would it work to connect two Facebook apps to one iOS app? This way, we could have the production site Facebook app connected to all platforms (preferable for implementing Facebook login) but still keep the say, iPhone Facebook app connected for marketing analysis.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't allow this.

Sorry :(

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Looks like with the latest Facebook SDK you need to have the info.plist entries, therefore you can only link to one FB app id.